# randtext not working

Tags: packages

All `\randomize{}` does in the following MWE is removing the space between the words.  I wonder why the text is not randomised.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{randtext}
\begin{document}
\randomize{Random Text}
\end{document}
```

I am using TeX Live.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `randtext` won't randomize as it looks. You can't copy paste the word.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{randtext}
\begin{document}
this is my randomized \randomize{Random Text} here.
\end{document}
```

This is how pdf looks:

[image]

When you try to copy paste the entire sentence from the resulting pdf, you get:

```
this is my randomized
n
x
m
t
o
d
e
T
Ra
here.
```

This package is meant to  prevent the copy paste-ability of email addresses. From documentation:

[image]

Unfortunately not all pdf readers obey this randomization. It works with sumatrapdf (for me) and not with adobe.

Comment: @cyberSingularity: Yes. PDF readers don't follow uniform rules. This is same as putting a security password to pdf files. Some readers open the files ignoring all the pass words!

Comment: (This is no attack, I am genuinely interested to know the answer to the question that I'm going to ask!) 
--
I compiled your code with pdfLatex on my ubuntu and default Document Viewer copied it correctly (un randomize). What is the point of this command if most of readers can reorder the text?

Comment: @Pouya: I don't know exactly :-)